# Send a single integer (as it is a valid JSON object) in an Alamofire post request

Tags: swift, api, post, request, alamofire

So I need to send only an integer to the API. A single integer is a valid JSON object, but Alamofire requires a dictionary as parameter. Is it even possible to send just an integer?

The error I got is this:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type
> 'Parameters?' (aka 'Optional<Dictionary<String, Any>>')

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but it looks like you can't send a single integer. Instead, you need to wrap it in a `Dictionary` with a key.

Answer (score 0):

hope your everything! Buddy!

Just a single integer is not a valid JSON.

presumably, send a single integer value to "text/plain" content type.

or, send a single integer value with key value.

example:

```
{"someKey":1}
```

let me know, anything else

Comment: **"Just a single integer is not a valid JSON"** this is not true. try `let dataInt = try! JSONEncoder().encode(1)` Btw you can also check using jsonlint https://jsonlint.com

Comment: Or using JSONSerialization `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: 1, options: .fragmentsAllowed)`

Answer (score 0):

Although @Peter is right and a single `Int` is not valid JSON (`JSONEncoder`s support not withstanding), you can accomplish this by send the `Int` directly as a parameter, you just need to use the overload of `request` that uses the `encoder` parameter instead of the `encoding` parameter.

```
request(..., encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default)
```